# Result of a corollary of Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem.

Tags: general-topology, analysis

This is a problem of the book  **Flemming-Functions of several variables**

Let A be a closed, convex, nonempty set, and $ \vec{x}_{0} \notin A. $ Show that there is exactly one point $ \vec{x}_{1} \in A $ nearest $ \vec{x}_{0}.$

The thing is that there is a Corollary of Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem and it says:

**Corollary 3:** Let $A$ be a closed, nonempty subset of $E^{n}$ and $ \vec{x}_{0} \in A.$ Then there exist $ \vec{x}_{1} \in A $ such that  $ | \vec{x} - \vec{x}_{0} | \geq | \vec{x}_{1} - \vec{x}_{0} |  $ for all $ \vec{x} \in A.$

So we can notice that the point $ \vec{x}_{1}$  need not be unique. However when the "convex" conditions is add the $ \vec{x}_{1}$ has to be unique, how do I start writting this problem? I don't know how to start, would you help me?

Comment: Is the ambient space finite dimensional? (If not, is is complete?) And what metric is used?

Comment: I presume the space would be a real/complex vector space, and the metric induced by an inner product, aren't they?

Comment: I assume there is an ambient inner product $(\cdot,\cdot)$ and "nearest" refers to the induced norm ? If not, the claim is false (take $\mathbb R^2$ with the infinity norm $||\cdot ||_\infty$ : $0$ has the all segment $\{1\}\times[0,1]$ as projection on the closed convex $\{1\}\times\mathbb R$).

Comment: Does $E^n$ stand for Euclidean $n$-space, that is $\mathbb R^n$ with the standard inner product?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but perhaps something like this might work : Define
$$
B = \{x \in A : |x-x_0| = d(x_0, A)\}
$$
Then, $B$ is non-empty (by the result you quoted), closed (since $A$ is) and convex, since for any $x,y \in B$ and $0\leq t \leq 1$,
$$
|tx + (1-t)y -x_0| \leq t|x-x_0| + (1-t)|y-x_0| \leq d(x_0,A)
$$
Since $tx + (1-t)y \in A$, it must be in $B$.

Furthermore, $B$ has empty interior (Geometrically, this is obvious, but a proof is needed), and so must be contained in a hyperplane (You need to prove this separately as well). Now note that
$$
d(x_0,A) = d(x_0, B)
$$
Therefore, the question now reduces to one involving $B$ instead of $A$. But $B \subset E^{n-1}$, so one can induct (the result is true if $A$ is contained in a line, for instance)